# Geometric Wedge Products of Two Currents and Push Forward a Current by an Automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, distribution-theory, complex-manifolds

**Harmonic Currents of Finite Energy and Laminations**, *J. E. Fornaess* and *N. Sibony*, *GAFA, Geom, Funct, Anal*, $2005$, $962-1003$.

Page $993$.

Let $\mathbb{P}^2$ be the Complex Projective Space and $$\varphi_{\varepsilon}:\mathbb{P}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$$$$\varphi_{\varepsilon}([a:b:c])=[a:b+\varepsilon a:c]$$ where $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{C}$, $\varphi_{\varepsilon}$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Let $T$ be a $(1,1)$ harmonic current on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Define $T_{\varepsilon}:=(\varphi_{\varepsilon})_*(T)$.

Th questions are

1. Suppose that $\omega$ is a $(1,1)$ form on $\mathbb{P}^2$, How to compute $T_{\varepsilon}(\omega)$???
2. What does the "geometric wedge product $T \bigwedge T_{\varepsilon}$" mean?

[image]

Comment: How about $(\Phi_\epsilon)_*(T)(\omega) = T(\Phi_\epsilon^*\omega)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin are you sure?

Comment: Yes. This is how all games with currents are played.

Comment: I wonder if $\varphi_\epsilon$ is well-defined if $c = 0$?

Comment: @red_trumpet If $\varepsilon=0$, then $\varphi_{\varepsilon}=I$ (the identity)